# Using Github pages on .gitignore content

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have a project that generates static resources that compose a website. It uses gulp, sass, and templating to output a static website to a folder at `dist/`. The content in this folder can be copied and served as a static website.

In the .gitignore I ignore the `dist/` folder as it's generated content that is a result of the project.

I want to use github pages to serve my static website, though. So essentially, I need to create a branch that contains only the content in the `dist/` folder, the opposite of the main branch.

Are there any good strategies for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new repository in `/dist` and point it to your publishing branch.

Code in `master` and site in `gh-pages` for project repository.

Code in `sources` and site in `master` for a user repository.